# create a pull subscription to transactional publication that uses FTP snapshot delivery in SQLServer Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-replication, transactional-replication

I've created a publisher that uses FTP snapshot delivery method using SSMS.
However, when I tried to configure Subscriber, I couldn't find option to use FTP credentials.

I read  "To create a pull subscription to a snapshot or transactional publication that uses FTP snapshot delivery" section in [How to: Deliver a Snapshot Through FTP (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146956(v=sql.105).aspx) and steps provided are for script.

I was wondering, if this can be achieved from SSMS, rather running it as script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I understand, if you use SSMS, you just need to config it at publisher side only.
For more information: [Deliver a Snapshot Through FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/deliver-a-snapshot-through-ftp)

Comment: Thank you for the comment blue qn. After creating subscription through wizard, I generated script of it. It shows as follows:

Comment: `exec sp_addpullsubscription_agent @publisher = N'MyServer', @publisher_db = N'PubDb', @publication = N'Myrep_demo', @distributor = N'MyServer', @distributor_security_mode = 1, @distributor_login = N'', @distributor_password = null, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', @frequency_type = 64, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0,   @alt_snapshot_folder = N'', @working_directory = N'', @use_ftp = N'True', @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @publication_type = 0`

I wonder, how it connects to publisher if it doesn't use FTP without username and password.

Comment: As I know, it will connect to publication and get ftp information.